# Compare strings while ignoring line endings

Tags: python

Problem:

```
stra = """ this
is
a
test 
line """

strb = " this is a test line"
```

stra is not equal to strb as the end line character is introduced in stra.

Please let me know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Not sure what you want "fixed". Those two strings are not equal, so you want something other than testing for equality. What exactly do you need?

Answer (score 3):

Using method [`strip`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.strip) to remove trailing characters:

```
>>> " x".strip()
"x"
>>> " x".strip() == "x ".strip()
True
```

Using method [`split`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.split) to compare string word-by-word:

```
>>> " x y\nz".split() # return list of "words" separated by whitespace characters
["x", "y", "z"]
>>> " x y\nz".split() == "x  y z".split()
True
```

Comment: Your recommendation works..but I need something different..Just updated the questions